# How can i link two tables in node.js?

Tags: node.js

So i have a Problem with adding two seperate tables in one JOIN table.
[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZblX.png)
[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpD6d.png)
I want to add dynamic weatherstations, but i dont know how to give the station_id the right weatherstation without doing it as a static input. My code right now is

```
//addStation js-file
app.post("/addStation", urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  
  var stationName = req.body.station_name;
  var latitudeNumber= req.body.latitude_number;
  var longitudeNumber=req.body.longitude_number;
  var stationId = req.body.station_number;
//also the stationId has no value idk why

  console.log(stationName,latitudeNumber,longitudeNumber,stationId);
  dbClient.query("INSERT INTO weatherstation (station,latitude,longitude) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)", [stationName,latitudeNumber,longitudeNumber], function (dbError, dbResponse) {
    dbClient.query("INSERT INTO weatherinformation (weather,temperature,wind,air) VALUES (0,0,0,0)",function (dbError,dbResponse){


      res.redirect("/Dashboard"); 


    });
  });

});
```

Now the pug file

```
extends layout.pug

block title 
    title Dashboard

block content

    h1.pb-2.border-bottom Dashboard
    
    each station in weatherinformation /*Fragen warum des so geht in der Reihenfolge der anordnung??*/
        form(action="/deleteStation",method="post")   
            .row
                // First Card 
                .col-xl-3.col-md-6.mb-4
                    .card.border-left-warning.shadow.h-100.py-2
                        .card-body 
                            .col.mr-2
                            .dashboard_text #{station.station}
                            .h5.mb-0.mr-3.font-weight-bold.text-white-800 Lat:#{station.latitude}
                            .h5.mb-0.mr-3.font-weight-bold.text-white-800 Lon:#{station.longitude}
                // Second Card
                .col-xl-3.col-md-6.mb-4
                    .card.border-left-warning.shadow.h-100.py-2
                        .card-body

                            .col.mr-2
                                .dashboard_text Wetter
                                .h5.mb-0.mr-3.font-weight-bold.text-white-800 #{station.weather}
                            .col-auto
                                i.fas.fa-dollar-sign.fa-2x.text-gray-300
                // Third Card
                .col-xl-3.col-md-6.mb-4
                    .card.border-left-warning.shadow.h-100.py-2
                        .card-body

                            .col.mr-2
                                .dashboard_text Temperatur
                                .col-auto
                                    .h5.mb-0.mr-3.font-weight-bold.text-white-800 #{station.temperature} Grad

                // Forth Card
                .col-xl-3.col-md-6.mb-4
                    .card.border-left-warning.shadow.h-100.py-2
                        .card-body
                            .col.mr-2
                                .dashboard_text Wind
                                .h5.mb-0.mr-3.font-weight-bold.text-white-800 #{station.wind} bft
                            .col-auto
                                i.fas.fa-comments.fa-2x.text-gray-300
                // Fifth Card            
                .col-xl-3.col-md-6.mb-4
                    .card.border-left-warning.shadow.h-100.py-2
                        .card-body

                            .col.mr-2
                                .dashboard_text Luftdruck
                                .h5.mb-0.mr-3.font-weight-bold.text-white-800 #{station.air} hpa
                            .col-auto
                                i.fas.fa-comments.fa-2x.text-gray-300                
                a.btn.btn-primary(href='/Details/'+station.id)     
                    i.bi.bi-archive-fill   
                button.btn.btn-primary
                    i.bi.bi-trash3-fill
        


    
    form.row.g-3.needs-validation(action="/addStation" method="post")
        .col-md-4(value name="station_number" type="number")
            label.form-label(for='validationCustom01') Station
            input#validationCustom01.form-control(type="text" name="station_name" placeholder='e.g Berlin')
        .col-md-4
            label.form-label(for='validationCustom02') Latitude
            input#validationCustom02.form-control(type="text" name='latitude_number' placeholder='Number') 
        .col-md-4
            label.form-label(for='validationCustom01') Longitude    
            input#validationCustom01.form-control(type='text' name='longitude_number' placeholder='Number')
        .col-12
            button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit" class="btn btn-primary") Submit >
```

Does somebody how to give the station_id dynamically the right value?
Help would be appreciated :)